# Formulation for IP of large OR statement which gives a good linear relaxation

Tags: numerical-methods, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, integer-programming, relaxations

Let $N$ be a very large number. I want a good way to program that $x$ should be one if and only if one of $x_i$ is equal to one.We can write the following Integer Programming problem:

\begin{align*}
\max x\\
x \leq \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\\
x_i \in \{0,1\}\\
x\in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}
Then clearly, we have that $x$ will be one whenever at least one $x_i$ is equal to one.

My problem with this is that when we take the Linear relaxation of this problem we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\max x\\
x \leq \sum_{i=1}^N x_i,\\
0 \leq x_i\\
0\leq x
\end{align*}
if now all $x_i = \frac{1}{N}$ we still obtain $x=1$ while for very large $N$ this is extremely inaccurate to what we actually want. I am thus looking for a way to rewrite the IP problem such that the linear relaxation behaves in a way that at least one $x_i$ needs to be large in order for $x$ to be large.

Notes :

1. This is only a part of a much larger IP problem, therefore I can not simply change the max with a min etc.
2. This $x$ is used as follows : I have in my problem an $x$ and a $y$ : the $x$ is $1$ when any of the $x_i$ is equal to $1$ while the $y$ is equal to $1$ if any of the $y_i$ is equal to one. Then we further have a $z$ which is one if both $x$ and $y$ are equal to $1$, we have:
   $z\leq x$
   $z\leq y$
   and we want to maximize $z$ (indeed then we get $z=1$ iff $x=1$ AND $y=1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 :**

Use Dantzig Wolfe decomposition, which is always at least as tight as the initial formulation. To do this, define the set $\Omega$ of combinations that define your "master problem" :
$$
\Omega := \{(x_1,x_2,...,x_N,x) \in \mathbb{B}^{N+1} \; | \; x=1 \Leftrightarrow \; \exists i\in | x_i=1 \}
$$
For example $(0,...,0) \in \Omega$, as well as $(1,...,1)$, or $(1,0,1,...,1)$.

And let $\lambda_i$ be a binary variable that takes value $1$ if and only if combination $i \in \Omega$ is selected.

Your problem can then be formulated as follows :
$$
\max \; \sum_{i\in \Omega | x =1} \lambda_i
$$
subject to 
$$
\sum_{i\in \Omega } \lambda_i = 1 \\
\lambda_i \in \{0,1\}
$$
You will certainly have to add the other constraints (that you have not explicitey written in your question).

You can easily generate $\Omega$ explicitely beforehand, or dynamically with column generation.

**Approach #2 :**

Transform the problem into the following minimization problem
$$
\min z
$$
subject to
\begin{align*}
&x_i \le x \quad \forall i=1,...,N \\
&y_i \le x \quad \forall i=1,...,N \\
&x +y  \le 2z \\
&x,y,z \in \mathbb{B} \\
&x_i,y_i  \in \mathbb{B}
\end{align*}

The constraint $x+y \le 2z$ makes sure that when $x=y=1$, $z$ takes value $1$. Otherwise, since you are minimizing $z$ it will take value $0$.

This formulation is interesting as the solution with $x_i=1/N$ and $x=1$ is not optimal when relaxing integrality constraints. Indeed, since you are minimizing $z$, if $x_i=1/N$, $x$ will also take value $1/N$ (and not $1$), in order for $z$ to be minimized in the constraint $x+y\le 2z$.

Comment: But this $x$ is exactly what I want to maximize, so penalizing for it doesn't really make sense here?

Comment: Then in that case use both constraints (yours and this one).

Comment: I don't see how your inequality $x_i \leq x$ is adding anything here : $x$ will automatically maximize itself thus with only the constraint $x \leq \sum_i x_i$ we will always have $x = \sum_i x_i \geq x_i$

Comment: The solution with $x_i = 1/N$, and $x=1$ is not optimal for the linear relaxation of  $\min\{ x \; | \; x_i \le x \quad x,x_i \in \mathbb{B} \}$ which is why the formulation is interesting. 
You are maximizing $x$, but $x$ cannot be larger than $1$, and $x$ can only take value $1$ if at least one $x_i$ takes value $1$. This is achieved with $\min\{ x \; | \; x_i \le x \quad x,x_i \in \mathbb{B} \}$.

Comment: OK I understand what you suggest : replace my IP problem with this minimization. I agree that this could be a possibility.

However in my current problem, this $x$ is merely a small part of a much greater optimization problem, therefore I can not simply "change" the maximization to minimization

Comment: how about adding $-x$ to the larger maximization problem's cost function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101599/discussion-between-holymonk-and-kuifje).

Comment: This is still a subset of a bigger IP problem, so changing the max to a min is no option here :/

Comment: @HolyMonk : I have proposed another approach :) hope it helps.

Comment: Approach 1 is indeed the method used to solve the larger problem. However, I am looking for a kind of "proprocessing method" to make this long numerical method more efficient. If no better solution comes along I will accept this as an answer by the end of the deadline.

Comment: Approach 1 still allows $(1/N,\dots,1/N,1)$ as a convex combination of vectors of the form $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0,1)\in \{0,1\}^{N+1}$, where the first 1 is in position $j$.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the relationship without depending on the objective or introducing additional variables.  Rewriting your logical proposition in conjunctive normal form somewhat automatically yields linear constraints:
\begin{equation}
x \iff \bigvee_i x_i \\
\left(x \implies \bigvee_i x_i\right) \bigwedge \left(\bigvee_i x_i \implies x\right) \\
\left(\neg x \lor \bigvee_i x_i\right) \bigwedge \left(\neg \bigvee_i x_i \lor x\right) \\
\left(\neg x \lor \bigvee_i x_i\right) \bigwedge \left(\bigwedge_i \neg x_i \lor x\right) \\
\left(\neg x \lor \bigvee_i x_i\right) \bigwedge \left(\bigwedge_i (\neg x_i \lor x)\right) \\
\left(1 - x + \sum_i x_i \ge 1\right) \bigwedge \left(\bigwedge_i (1 - x_i + x \ge 1)\right) \\
\left(x \le \sum_i x_i\right) \bigwedge \left(\bigwedge_i (x_i \le x)\right)
\end{equation}
That is,
\begin{align}
x &\le \sum_i x_i\\
x_i &\le x &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

Comment: yes, I understand this and why it is true. What I am asking is whether we can change this $x \leq \sum_i x_i$ which makes the inequality more tight in case $x,x_i \in (0,1)$

Comment: This does not eliminate the solution $x_i = 1/N$, $x=1$.